# How to create a stripe invoice with a subscription_threshold billing reason?

Tags: stripe-payments

I'm making use of the [Billing Threshold](https://stripe.com/docs/products-prices/pricing-models#thresholds) concept that Stripe provides. AS part of this, I want my backend to react to invoices made when a customer reaches a billing threshold.

I've found that [Invoices](https://stripe.com/docs/api/invoices/object) have a `billing_reason` property which can have a value of `subscription_threshold`.

Unfortunately, I can't seem to figure out how to directly make an invoice with `billing_reason='subscription_threshold'` using the Stripe API. Is that possible?

I've found that I can use the Stripe API to [create usage records](https://stripe.com/docs/api/usage_records/create). However, it takes stripe up to 10 minutes in my experience between a billing threshold being reached and the relevant invoice being generated. This makes testing untenable.

Is there a way to make an invoice using the Stripe Invoice API with a custom billing reason?

Comment: Are you trying to do unit testing here? or is it just testing your webhook flow?

Comment: I'm trying to do manual and e2e testing. I just ran through a manual flow with creating usage records and it took 40 minutes for the invoice to be generated after the billing threshold was reached.

Comment: Stripe doesn't support e2e testing, and you shouldn't be doing that anyways. For manual testing you can use [test clocks](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/testing/test-clocks) to speed things up.